# What is the URL format in grails?

Tags: grails

Hi I'm very new to Grails. I have set of api's that I wish to test. By using `curl` command I can test those api's like this:

```
curl --verbose https://x.x.x.in/init_order     -u x-x-x-x-x-x-x-B4E4E:     -d "amount=400.00"     -d "order_id=xxxxxx"     -d "customer_id=xxxxx101"     -d "customer_email=customer@mail.com"
```

This will give a response in JSON.

What I want is I need to hit this url. I thought `?` is the separtor in `params` of grails. But when I do something like this:

```
 https://x.x.x.in/init_order/x.x.x.x.x?no=123?no2=234
```

and `print` the params, I can see I get `no` as `123?no2=234`. Here the `?` is not separating my params.

Very new to Grails, I wonder where I'm making the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not grails specific.  In HTTP you use `?` to start the parameter list then `&` to separate the parameters from each other.

The default URL Mapping is `/$controller/$action?/$id?`

So if you had `BookController` with an action of `findBooks` and wanted to pass in parameters author and title it would look like:

`http://yourdomain.com/book/findBooks?author=Grisham&title=Firm`

Comment: is grails using 'standard' rest api? I mean it would be cleaner to generate links like this: _show_ - `GET /book/{id}`, _save_ - `POST /book`, _update_ - `PUT /book/id`. why do we have to specify __action__ in url?